# Structs duplication in Julia

Tags: struct, julia

I have package called `sandwich`, it then has:

A file `flavours.jl` which defines a struct `HamCheeseSandwich`.

The file `factory.jl` is a module which first first runs `include("flavours.jl")` and has a method `make_sandwich` which creates a `HamCheeseSandwich`, except rather than producing a `HamCheeseSandwich` it returns `sandwich.factory.HamCheeseSandwich`

The last file is `printer.jl` , here the sandwich made in `factory.jl` fails with `MethodError: no method matching print_sandwich(::sandwich.factory.HamCheeseSandwich)`

```
# printer.jl
function print_sandwich(sandwich::HamCheeseSandwich)
    println("Enjoy your sandwich")
    println(sandwich)
end
```

When I check the types

```
Julia> sandwich.factory.HamCheeseSandwich == HamCheeseSandwich
false
```

Which suggests the problem is my use of `include` has created two versions of `HamCheeseSandwich`.

### To reproduce

A working example can be seen at this repo:https://github.com/this-josh/Julia-structs-question

This behaviour can be reproduced with

```
using sandwich
s = factory.make_sandwich(true,false)
print_sandwich(s)
```

My question is how should I use includes within my package to prevent the duplication of `HamCheeseSandwich` and to make sure I can still type hint as in `printer.jl`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are defining the type `HamSandwich` several times and you should do it once and then reference the definition.

Hence your code should be:

```
module Sandwich
  module Flavours
    struct HamSandwich end
  end
  module Factory
     import ..Flavours
     makeSandwich() = Flavours.HamSandwich()
  end 
end
```

Testing:

```
julia> using Main.Sandwich

julia> Sandwich.Factory.makeSandwich()
Main.Sandwich.Flavours.HamSandwich()
```